# Set peoplepicker default value with current user with JS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm using sharepoint services 3.0 and I've created a custom list form. I have in this form a peoplepicker field and need it to be set by default to the current user.

This is what I've got so far:

- First my peoplepicker fonction:

  function PeoplePicker(){

  ```
  this.context = null;
  this.web = null;
  this.currentUser = null;
  this.parentTagId = null

  this.SetParentTagId = function(id){
      this.parentTagId = id;
  }

  this.SetLoggedInUser = function(){
      if(this.parentTagId != null){
          this.getWebUserData();
      }
  }

  this.getWebUserData = function(){
      this.context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      this.web = this.context.get_web();
      this.currentUser = this.web.get_currentUser();
      this.currentUser.retrieve();
      this.context.load(this.web);
      this.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),
                                     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
  }

  this.onSuccessMethod = function(){
      this.setDefaultValue(this.currentUser.get_title());
  }

  this.onFailureMethod = function(){
      alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
  }

  this.setDefaultValue = function(value){
      var parentTag = document.getElementById(this.parentTagId);
      if (parentTag != null) {
          var peoplePickerTag = this.getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle(parentTag, 'div',
                                                  'UserField_upLevelDiv', 'People Picker');
          if (peoplePickerTag) {
              peoplePickerTag.innerHTML = value;
          }
      }
  }

  this.getTagFromIdentifierAndTitle = function(parentElement, tagName, identifier, title){
      var len = identifier.length;
      var tags = parentElement.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
      for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
          var tempString = tags[i].id;
          if (tags[i].title == title && (identifier == "" ||
                              tempString.indexOf(identifier) == tempString.length - len)) {
              return tags[i];
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```

  }
- secondly the way I use it in my asp content :

> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SetWebUserData, "PeoplePicker.js");
>
> function SetWebUserData() {
>       var pplPicker = new PeoplePicker();
>       // Set the parent tag id of the people the picker.
>       pplPicker.SetParentTagId('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_g_ec44fef5_c1a6_4ade_b7e4_2b80803724a1_ff6_1_ctl00_ctl00_UserField');
>       pplPicker.SetLoggedInUser(); }

But nothing happens when I load the form...Am I using the wrong parent tag ID? I took it from the source code of the page...

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){
var columnName = 'Manager Name';   
var searchText = RegExp("FieldName=\"" + columnName + "\"", "gi");
$("td.ms-formbody").each(function() {  
if(searchText.test($(this).html())) {  
$(this).find("div[Title='People Picker']").html(getUserName());  
return false;  
}  
});
function getUserName() { 
var wshell=new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell"); 
var userName=wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");  
return userName;}   
});
</script>
```

My people picker field is named 'Manager Name' but it is a variable so you can change it. I use the function getUserName() to set the value of the people picker. getUserName uses the Environment String username. Some people will tell you that is not the best thing to use because it can be 'faked'. I am in a corporate environment where this is tightly controlled. Personally I don't think most user will even know how to do that.

I think the issue you are having is the value a people picker field needs is not just a string. I believe it is looking for a key value pair which would mean you need the user name and ID number assigned in the SharePoint site. To get around this the code I use just puts the username sting in the html form field.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i have implemented, here i had passed the username as a querystring and if not than populated with the current user. Modify as per your needs.

```
        var Dname = queryString('DName'); 
        if(Dname!= null)
        {       
            var pp = getPickerInputElement('Employee');
            if(pp != null)
            {
                pp.innerHTML =Dname;
                document.getElementById('Emp').innerHTML=Dname;
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            fillPeoplePickerWithCurrentUser('Employee');
        }   
function fillPeoplePickerWithCurrentUser(pickerName)
    {
        var currentUser =getUserData();
    }
function getUserData() 
    {   
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();             
        web = context.get_web(); 
        currentUser = web.get_currentUser(); 

        currentUser.retrieve(); 
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onFaiureMethodl);
    }
```

Comment: What's DName? Would I need to replace the Username with DName, how would I automate this to get the current logged in user?

Comment: 'Dname' is querystring parameter in above case i.e username was passed as a QS parameter. You can use SPServices to get the current user.